# Unique elements of an array of arrays with "issetequal"

Tags: julia

For an array like

```
v=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]
```

I am looking for a method to delete all entries that are duplicated in the sense that they are equal when considered as sets. 
In this example, `issetequal([1,2,3],[2,3,1]) = true`, so the method should return the array `[[1,2],[1,2,3]]`.

In principle, something like `unique(issetequal, v)` would solve the problem. But in practice, this option gives the error

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching issetequal(::Array{Int64,1})

Does anybody have a sugestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.unique), we see that this form of `unique` takes as first argument a unary function:

```
unique(f, itr)


  Returns an array containing one value from itr for each unique value produced by f applied to elements of itr.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> unique(x -> x^2, [1, -1, 3, -3, 4])
  3-element Array{Int64,1}:
   1
   3
   4
```

In your example, `issetequal` is a binary function that directly checks the set-equality of two values. What you want instead is the `Set` constructor, which constructs a `Set` out of an `Array`. You can then let `unique` test the equality between sets:

```
julia> unique(Set, [[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,1]])
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]   
 [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Great response! Thanks.